# How to filter an order collection by cancelled items?

Tags: collection, sales-order, collection-filtering, items

Is it possible to filter an Mage_Sales_Model_Order collection by item ids?

I need a collection but there are some items inside that I don't want.

I tried it with:

```
$canceledItemIds = array(101,102,103);
    $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    $orderModel->getCollection()
               ->join(array('item' => 'sales/order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = item.order_id')
               ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', $canceledItemIds);
```

But that had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Since the ID's are an array you need an `IN` statement

```
$canceledItemIds = array(101,102,103);
    $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    $orderModel->getCollection()
               ->join(array('item' => 'sales/order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = item.order_id')
               ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', array('IN' => $canceledItemIds));
```

**for remove multiple/duplicated row for an order**

```
$orderModel->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id')
```

Comment: sander please add -group('main_table.entity_id')

Comment: @AmitBera not sure what you mean. Feel free to edit my answer! :)

Comment: The strange thing is that it sounds good but the result is an collection with all items. It seems that it has no effect to add the filter.

But I guess I have another solution:
In sales_flat_order_items is a column 'qty_canceled'. This seems easier to filter. But again when I try to filter items with an value of '0' that means all items that are not canceled I get also a collection all items.

Maybe I'm to stupid for this.
'

Answer (score 1):

Hi remove load function from `->load($order->getId());` for getting order-collection filter by item id.AS sander say need to use **in**  at collection condition.

`Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId())` wil give you particular order it object and does not provide all order collection.
More about  filter see [at](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) .

### For getting a collection please try with format

```
Mage::getModel('modelsPrefix/modelname')->getCollection();
```

thus you can get order collection by

```
Mage::getModel('sales/colllection')->getCollection();





$canceledItemIds = array(101,102,103)   
 $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
$orderModel->getCollection()
               ->join(array('item' => 'sales/order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = item.order_id')
               ->addFieldToFilter('item_id',array('in', $canceledItemIds));
```

**then remove the duplicate and multiple rows for each order when order have multiple items use group by**

```
$orderModel->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

**Note:** `item_id` give the `order item id not product i`d.Forgetting product id try use field `product_id`.See at `sale_flat_order_item` table at db